# The type initializer for 'Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory' threw an exception

Tags: c#, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, typeinitializeexception

I'm following the directions on [Quartz.Net's tutorial](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/tutorial/index.html) pretty closely, but I'm getting a start error when trying to debug my project.

```
 The type initializer for 'Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory' threw an exception.
```

I couldn't really find any help online.  Is this a configuration problem?  Anybody know where I can get a straightforward list of what needs to be configured?

(I'm using Quartz.Net 2.0)

INNER EXCEPTION: {"Failed obtaining configuration for Common.Logging from configuration section 'common/logging'."}

Comment: What is inner exception?

Answer (score 4):

You most likely do not reference all required assemblies e.g. "Common.Logging.dll".

**Update**

The constructor fails because your `app.config` or `web.config` does not contain a section for `common\logging`. Does your `.config` file contains the following section:

```
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, Common.Logging" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Simple.TraceLoggerFactoryAdapter, Common.Logging">
        <arg key="level" value="DEBUG" />
        <arg key="showLogName" value="true" />
        <arg key="showDataTime" value="true" />
        <arg key="dateTimeFormat" value="yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:fff" />
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>
```

Comment: I am referencing Quartz.dll, Common.Logging.dll, and C5

Comment: The error occurs because of an static constructor failing. The only external reference in `StdSchedulerFactory` is Common.Logging `private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (StdSchedulerFactory));`

Is "Common.Logging.dll" copied to your output folder. Could you please post the inner exception.

Comment: Common.Logging.dll is in my output folder.  See my edit for the inner exception.

Comment: I have that stuff verbatim in my app.config file.  Still no go.

Comment: I have no clue why it's to working with a proper config. You could upload your project somewhere and let me have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you, I was stuck for 1 day on this problem. A little advice: if in your .config file there is a `<startup></startup>` section, it must declared after Common.logging section or it could be raised an Common.Logging config exception

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was the version of the Quartz.net.

Initially I used the latest version of Quartz.net and had the same error. Now I am using:

- Common.Logging 2.1.2.0
- Common.Logging.Log4Net1211 2.1.0.0
- log4net 1.2.11.0
- Quartz 2.2.2.400

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have added a reference to `Common.Logging.Log4Net` dll in your solution.

If not you can find a compatible `Common.Logging.Log4Net` dll in `Quartz.NET-2.0.1\lib\2.0`:

[Download Quartz.NET-2.0.1.zip (9.7 MB)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/quartznet/files/quartznet/Quartz.NET%202.0.1/)

Also you might need to use log4net version `1.2.10.0`.