# Why does Quartz.NET running in a Windows Service work just fine in Debug, but not in Release?

Tags: windows-services, quartz.net

I've created a Web API app that runs self-hosted (OWIN) inside of a Windows Service. The Web API portion of the app is a wrapper for submitting jobs to Quartz.NET. I'm using AdoJobStore for job persistence.

The whole thing works beautifully when built in Debug mode. I even have units test around it that submit jobs, read them, and then delete them. The tests pass flawlessly. But when I run it in Release mode, the service fails to start and gives me:

> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

When I dig into the logs, I see that the root error is:

> Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>   Stack:
>      at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.Initialize()
>      at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.GetScheduler()
>      at ARI.Scheduler.WindowsService.Program.Main()

My first thought was that the App.config must be missing from the Release folder. But it is indeed there. So, then I tried configuring the StdSchedulerFactory programatically instead. But the error remains.

**EDIT:**

Okay, so digging a little further, I've wrapped the call to GetScheduler() in a try-catch and I'm writing the base exception to the EventLog. The message it this:

> Exception Info: System.TypeInitializationException
>   Stack:
>      at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.ValidateConfiguration()
>      at Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.Initialize(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection)
>      at ARI.Scheduler.WindowsService.Program.InitializeScheduler()
>      at ARI.Scheduler.WindowsService.Program.Main()

I'm beating my head against the wall on this one. Any help from the Quartz.NET team would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: When you run app in debug mode, do you start Quartz.NET service at the same time?

Comment: I was originally starting up the Quartz.NET scheduler service in the OnStart() method of the Windows Service. That works just fine in a Debug build. Then, when I started getting the Error 1053, I instead fired of the Quartz.NET initialization in a thread, as was suggested in several post I found around the web about Windows Services and Error 1053. Again, this works just fine in Debug, but still errors out in Release a build when the Windows Service starts. So, still not working.

Comment: What I don't understand is the System.IO.FileNotFoundException in Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory.Initialize(). This leads me to believe that the App.config is missing, but it's not. So, then I'm led to believe that possibly some assembly is missing. But why would it be missing from Release and not from Debug? The output folders for each build type contain the exact same files, so it doesn't appear that anything is missing from the Release folder.

Comment: Added an edit in the question with exception info closer to the source.

Answer (score 1):

Sonofabitch. It was a log4net assembly version mismatch. Gawd!!!

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.11.0" newVersion="1.2.11.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Needs to be:

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="log4net" publicKeyToken="669e0ddf0bb1aa2a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.2.11.0" newVersion="1.2.13.0" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

Note the **3** in 1.2.13.0, instead of being 1.2.11.0. This was the post that led me to the possibility that it was an assembly problem: [The type initializer for 'Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory' threw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7997725/the-type-initializer-for-quartz-impl-stdschedulerfactory-threw-an-exception)

Guess I'd better pay better attention to my assembly versions. I still don't understand why Debug mode worked just fine, because both Debug and Release are currently using the same App.config. Weird.